# Collection that loses oldest elements on add()

Tags: java

I'm looking for a Java class that implements `Collection` and loses oldest elements when I `add()` a new one, if total number of elements is bigger than X. Does it exist or I have to implement it myself?

I need a thread-safe one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Ring Buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread-safe circular buffer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079210/thread-safe-circular-buffer-in-java)

Comment: [This](http://www.museful.net/2012/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java) might help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apart from Linkedhasmap if you are looking for list type solution, Google guava has [EvictingQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html). And for thread safety you must wrap it in a synchronized wrapper ([Queues#synchronizedQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#synchronizedQueue(java.util.Queue))).

```
EvictingQueue<String> q = EvictingQueue.create(3);
Queue<String> syncQ =  Queues.synchronizedQueue(q);
syncQ.add("one");
syncQ.add("two");
syncQ.add("three");
syncQ.add("four");
System.out.println(q); // Prints [two, three, four]
```

Comment: I think you could achieve that by `Queues.synchronizedQueue(q);` again from guava.

Answer (score 3):

> [`CircularFifoQueue`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) is a first-in first-out queue with a fixed size that replaces its
>   oldest element if it is full.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) to do precisely that, quoting the Javadoc:

```
// Sample use: this override will allow the map to grow up to 100 entries and then delete the 
// eldest entry each time a new entry is added, maintaining a steady state of 100 entries.

 private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 100;

 protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
    return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
 }
```

for thread safe-ness you can wrap it using [Collections.synchronizedmap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [EvictingQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) added at v.15 of Google Guava to implement Moving Average functionality in the past.

It is not thread-safe though.

Comment: that's a 404 - where did it go? Did Google remove it ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere thanks - replaced it with the new location of the javadocs